# S3 Glacier 35 random restore per PB limit

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

[In the doc goes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/restoring-objects.html):

> However, if you need to restore a large amount of data, keep in mind
> that the S3 Glacier and S3 Glacier Deep Archive storage classes are
> designed for **35 random restore requests per pebibyte (PiB) stored per
> day**.

Upon scouting the API docs and other docs I could not find a second reference to this limit. Also my experiments show that I can archive and restore 300+ small objects to Deep Archive without hitting this limit.

[Also in a whitepaper goes](https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/serverless-fixity-for-digital-preservation-compliance/latest/serverless-fixity-for-digital-preservation-compliance.pdf):

> If you need to run this solution on  a  large  number  of  objects  in
> Glacier  or  Deep  Archive,  keep  in  mind  that  these  storage
> classes are designed for 35 random restore requests per pebibyte (PiB)
> stored per day. You can  increase  restore  throughput  by  sequencing
> restores  by  object  creation  date  to  reduce randomness. You can
> also spread checksum calculations over a number of days or weeks to
> remain  below  therandom  restore  entitlement  and  maintain  restore
> throughput  for  other access needs.

This only adds more confusion as how "randomness" is defined.

Moreover, I found that the `InitiateJob` API is not armed with `429 Resource Limit Exceeded`.

So, what exactly are "random restore requests"? What is the implication of this limit?

Comment: Are you intending to use Glacier **directly** (eg via `InitiateJob`), or are you intending to use Glacier via Amazon S3 (which is the only way to get _Deep Archive_ pricing)? These days, it is much easier to go via S3 than direct to Glacier.

Comment: Yeah but still we need to figure out what this magical number 35 means. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: It merely says "designed for". I read it as meaning "if you want to do much more than this, then Glacier storage probably isn't the right storage class for your needs". It is designed for **infrequent access to archived data**, and that is their definition of _infrequent_.

Comment: While an exact number here looks odd to me, in the second doc it also mentions "random restore **entitlement**" which to me clearly marks this as a quota instead of a suggestion. @JohnRotenstein